# How can I split strings so that only numbers are selected?

Tags: python, regex

> please excuse me for the change in this question

**I want to split a string** (e.g. text1, text2)**, so that only numbers are output:**

I tried the following:

```
import re

# example text1

text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"

split_text1 = re.split(" +", text1)

print(split_text1)

['', 'climb', '-', '95/', '85', '0.18', 'low', '-', '4680']

# example text2

text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"

split_text2 = re.split(" +", text2)

print(split_text2)

['CD 3 TO', 'F TO GD', '.80000E+02', '.00000E+00', '.00000E+00', '.00000E+00 /']
```

How can I get as result:

```
# split_text1 = ['95', '85', '0.18', '4680']

# split_text2 = ['3', '80.0','0.0', '0.0', 0.0]
```

Comment: "My problem is that " 95/ 85" should be not be splitted." *Why*? What is the underlying logic here? How come, for example, `-  4680` *should* be split? How do you know, and why is that different from the `/` case?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel:
I have changed my question. The problem is, the further code (not from me) is: `climb_cas = re.split("/+", split_text[3])` 
with `climb_cas_lo = float(climb_cas[0])`and 
`climb_cas_hi = float(climb_cas[1])`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. *What is the rule that tells you* that `95/ 85` should not be split, but `-  4680` should be split? The further code can't help me understand that rule, because I didn't ask *why* it needs to be split that way. I am asking about *how* it should be split, in precise detail.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Now I understand what you want. I need fom the text line only the numbers.

Comment: Why is `95/ 85` a number, instead of `95` and `85`? Why is `4680` the number you want, instead of `-4680`?

Comment: "please excuse me for the change in this question" Oh, I see. No, that's completely different, and invalidates what has been said so far. Please start over with a new question.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: next time I will do it as you propose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First version of the question:

You can ask to split with at least 2 spaces

```py
import re

text = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"

split_text = re.split("\s{2,}", text)

print(split_text)
# [' climb', '-', '95/ 85', '0.18', 'low', '-', '4680']
```

Works too without regex

```py
text = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"

split_text = text.split('  ')

print(split_text)
# [' climb', ' -', '95/ 85', '', ' 0.18', ' low', '', ' -', '4680']
```

With some more manipulation, you can also remove extra spaces

```py
text = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"

split_text = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), text.split('  ')))

print(split_text)
# ['climb', '-', '95/ 85', '', '0.18', 'low', '', '-', '4680']
```

---

Revised question

You need to match numbers (`\d` in regex), some are floats (so we need to match a single dot), some are exponential (we need to match `E+`)

Something like that should be a good start

```py
import re

regex = r'[\d.E+-]+' # try to match `E` and negatives

text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"
text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"

results1 = re.findall(regex, text1)
# ['-', '95', '85', '0.18', '-', '4680']

results2 = re.findall(regex, text2)
# ['3', '.80000E+02', '.00000E+00', '.00000E+00', '.00000E+00']
```

It matches a single `-` without numbers, we can be more specific for negative numbers.

```py
import re

regex = r'-?\d+[\d.E+-]*'

text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"
text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"

results1 = re.findall(regex, text1)
# ['95', '85', '0.18', '4680']

results2 = re.findall(regex, text2)
# ['3', '80000E+02', '00000E+00', '00000E+00', '00000E+00']
```

You need to transform exponential to a float form, again, a map should do it

```py
import re

regex = r'-?\d+[\d.E+-]*'

text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"
text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"

results1 = list(map(float, re.findall(regex, text1)))
# [95.0, 85.0, 0.18, 4680.0]

results2 = list(map(float, re.findall(regex, text2)))
# [3.0, 8000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

To be closest to your proposition

```py
import re

regex = r'-?\d+[\d.E+-]*'

def transform(value):
    if 'E' in value:
        return str(float(value))
    
    return value

text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"
text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"

results1 = list(map(transform, re.findall(regex, text1)))
# ['95', '85', '0.18', '4680']

results2 = list(map(transform, re.findall(regex, text2)))
# ['3', '8000000.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

And I just see now that my regex miss the first dot....

```py
import re

regex = r'-?(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)(?:E[+-]\d+)?'

def transform(value):
    if 'E' in value:
        return str(float(value))
    
    return value

text1 = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"
text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"

results1 = list(map(transform, re.findall(regex, text1)))
# ['95', '85', '0.18', '4680']

results2 = list(map(transform, re.findall(regex, text2)))
# ['3', '80.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

To explain a little, `-?` it may start with minus.

`(?: )` group without capturing, easier to group without changing the result

`\d*\.\d+` match at least a dot and numbers after, may match numbers before the dot

`|` simple or

`\d+` match any numbers

`(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)` everything together, so a group without capture that match any float or any integer

`[+-]` can be `+` or `-`

`(?:E[+-]\d+)?` quite the same, it a group without capture that match an `E` followed by `+` or `-` with any integer after, the group itself can be here one time or never (the last `?`)

Comment: Please see the revised question.

Comment: Please see the revised answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a second space before the +. This will stop the 95/ 85 from being split. If you want \n at the end of the last item, add text += "\n".

```
import re

text = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"

text = "a " + text

text += "\n"

split_text = re.split("  +", text)

if split_text[0] == "a":
  split_text[0] = ""
else:
  split_text[0] = split_text[0][2:]

print(split_text)
```

Comment: the third item is 95/ 85 tho

Comment: Please see the revised question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use findall to get the numeric patterns and convert the strings to float or int:

```
import re
def getNums(S):
    pattern = r"[+-]?(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)(?:[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?"
    result = []
    for part in re.findall(pattern,S):
        try:
            result.append(float(part))
            result[-1] = int(part)
        except ValueError:pass
    return result
                
text = " climb   -  95/ 85     0.18   low     -  4680"
print(getNums(text))
# [95, 85, 0.18, 4680]

text2 = "CD 3 TO   F TO GD   .80000E+02   .00000E+00   .00000E+00   .00000E+00 /"#
print(getNums(text2))
# [3, 80.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

*I'm assuming you want the output to be all numeric values rather than a mix of reformatted strings and numerics*

Here's a breakdown of the expression:

- `[+-]?` Optional leading sign
- `(?:[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)` Mandatory central part (non-capturing group)

  - `...|...` either start with a digit or with a decimal point
  - `[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*` start with digit(s) with optional decimal point and optional fractional digits
  - `\.[0-9]+`start with a decimal point followed by one or more digits (i.e. a decimal point without digits on the left or right is not a number.)
- `(?:[Ee][+-][0-9]+)?` Optional exponent part (non-capturing group)

  - `E` oe `e` to indicate start of exponent part
  - `[+-]?` optional sign of exponent
  - `[0-9]+` mandatory exponent digits

Comment: Please see the revised question.

Comment: Please see revised answer :)